# Recursive factorial which report error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Tags: python

I wrote a recursive factorial:

```
In [2]: %paste      
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1: return 1
    if n > 1 : n * factorial(n-1)
print(factorial(3))

## -- End pasted text --
```

but it report error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-da8388695f0c> in <module>
      2     if n == 1: return 1
      3     if n > 1 : n * factorial(n-1)
----> 4 print(factorial(3))

<ipython-input-10-da8388695f0c> in factorial(n)
      1 def factorial(n):
      2     if n == 1: return 1
----> 3     if n > 1 : n * factorial(n-1)
      4 print(factorial(3))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I could not find where a `NoneType` is returned.

Interestingly, When I input to ipython line by line, it works.

```
In [11]: def fact(n): 
    ...:     if n == 1: return 1 
    ...:     if n > 1 : return n * fact(n-1) 
    ...:            

In [12]: fact(3)    
Out[12]: 6
```

What's the problem with the first solution?

Solution 1 is identical to solution 2, why solution 2 not report error?

Comment: those snippets are not identical, look carefully, the first one lacks a `return`. This is a good example of why you sould stick to PEP8 and break up `if-elif-else` statements into blocks, and not as single lines. It would have been clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything when `n` is not 1. Change to this:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n > 1: return n * factorial(n-1)
    return 1
print(factorial(3))
```

On your IPython block you added the missing return, but it would return None for negative numbers.

Comment: `if n > 1 : return n * fact(n-1) `, I assumed that no negative will get. but it report error `unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: Well... Factorial for negative numbers are not as simple as with positive numbers. The issue with your code was just the missing return. You can keep both ifs to return `None` for negatives and fractions

Comment: the problem is that solution 2 works which identical to solution 1.

Comment: They are not identical, the third line of the result of your `%paste` command is missing the return after the `if`

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the factorial of n> 1

```
def factorial(n):
    if n > 1:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    return 1

print(factorial(3))
```